# Adding a "module" link on the header of a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im trying to edit a wordpress to have a link at the top of the site similar to this website: http://www.jakegosskuehn.com/. I haven't touched WP in years and I think in terms of joomla terms like modules.

I am trying to get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xT8k.png

Comment: There are a ton of links on the top of the site you reference.  I have no idea what you are actually asking how to do in your question.

Comment: I was trying to get a box of its own below the links on the page akin to the secondary website. It would be large enough to warrant attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends there are so many ways to skin a cat...

If there isn't a home.php or front_page.php in the template I might make one or edit it.

Otherwise you could modify the header.php and use something like is_home() or is_front_page() to check if I was on the home page and display the "box".

If their template is nice and you check the header.php and find a template hook like `<?php do_action('xxx_after_post_title'); ?>`.  Then you could just add what you wanted in the functions.php like:

```
function wpr_after_post_title() {
  echo "<div id="special-box">Stuff</div>";
}

add_action('wpr_after_post_title','wpr_after_post_title');
```

It all really depends on you, the developer.  I used to do a lot of Joomla sites too some days I miss the conformity of having everything in MVC but then I remember all of the extra nonsense it required.